# Create a href link on canvas in processing.js

Tags: processing.js

// my problem description is here

i use this code in processing.js

```
void setup(){

size(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
} 

void draw()
{
   fill(0,0,0);
   text("About",760,312);
}
```

My question is i want to make **About** is an href link. when i click that **About** it will display some page.So i want to know how to make ?????

Thanking u.. waiting for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can create links in PJS, and there are some examples in the PJS references.  In particular, [this page](http://processingjs.org/source/canvas-text-links/canvas-text-link.html) has some code on it with an 'alink' class which handles mouseovers and clicking.  Alternatively, you can use the [`link` method](http://processingjs.org/reference/link_) in a call to `mousePressed()` to handle sending the user somewhere when they click on your canvas.

Edited to ask: Also, just to ask, why not just put the links outside of the PJS in the first place?  If you add them as normal HTML your life will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a link-spawning area yourself, since the sketch is not a webpage. Some code to get you started:

```
ArrayList links = new ArrayList();

void setup()
{
  size(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
  links.add(new Link("About...",30,height/2,
                     "Arial",16,"www.stackoverflow.com");
} 

void draw()
{
  fill(0,0,0);
  text("About",760,312);
} 

class Link
{
  String ltext,fontname,url = "";
  int x,y,tsize=0;
  float tw=0;
  Link(String t, int _x, int _y, String fn, int ts, String _url) {
    ltext=t; x=_x; y=_y;
    fontname = fn; tw=textWidth(ltext); tsize=ts;
    url=_url; }
  draw() { textFont(createFont(fontname,tsize)); fill(0); text(ltext, x, y); }
  void mouseOver(int xy, int yo) { return x<xo && y-ts<yo && xo<x+tw && yo<y; }
}

void mousePressed()
{
  for(Object o: links)
  {
    Link l = (Link) o;
    if(l.mouseOver(mouseX,mouseY))
    {
      // This is a plain javascript instruction - to do this
      // properly, use a js interface instead,  as described in
      // http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/PomaxGuide#sketchtojs
      location = l.url;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is about PJS, not normal Processing.

Comment: It was, but that doesn't change the answer; the idea behind Processing.js is to let you write a Processing "sketch" and run it on the web. One correction on the answer I gave though: instead of of the pure js code "location = l.url" we can use the Processing "link()" method: "if(l.mouseOver(mouseX,mouseY)) { link(l.url); }"

Comment: You're absolutely right, I stand corrected.  The ArrayList threw me for a loop but I see now that it is allowed.